# Automatic reboot after suspend

Tags: linux-mint, suspend, reboot, bugs

I'm a new user to Linux Mint and I've had issues with the graphic driver.
I updated the kernel to 5.8 which solves the problem of adjusting the brightness or being able to wake up from suspend.
But now my new problem is that after waking up from suspend, the computer automatically restarts just in a few minutes.
Can anyone suggest what I should do? Thanks!

The following is what I got from

```
inxi -Fxxxrz



  System:
  Kernel: 5.8.0-55-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 wm: muffin 4.8.1 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 
  Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20TA005GIV v: ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 
  serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20TA005GIV serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO 
  v: R1EET34W(1.34 ) date: 02/25/2021 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 36.1 Wh condition: 45.0/45.0 Wh (100%) volts: 12.2/11.3 
  model: Celxpert 5B10X026 type: Li-poly serial: <filter> 
  status: Discharging cycles: 2 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 
  type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 44851 
  Speed: 1200 MHz min/max: 400/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1200 2: 1200 
  3: 1200 4: 1200 5: 1200 6: 1200 7: 1199 8: 1195 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  chip ID: 8086:9a49 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:a0c8 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-55-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
  chip ID: 8086:a0f0 
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 04:00.0 
  chip ID: 10ec:8168 
  IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 66.47 GiB (13.9%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZALQ512HALU-000L1 
  size: 476.94 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> rev: BL1QFXV7 
  scheme: GPT 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 66.46 GiB (14.2%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: 42.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Repos:
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
  1: deb http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyssa main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main
  2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
  3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
  4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
  6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
Info:
  Processes: 248 Uptime: 5m Memory: 15.35 GiB used: 1.36 GiB (8.9%) 
  Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash 
  v: 5.0.17 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the messages of ring buffer might help you to figure out what causing your system abrupt restarts.

By using `dmesg` command you can access messages stored in the ring buffer.

Type `sudo dmesg -L -T` command to review system recent logs on startup and shutdown.

As you have also mentioned that your system automatically restarts after of couple of minutes, you can try `--follow` option and might redirect the output to a file, something like below

```bsh
sudo dmesg -L -T | tee /tmp/dmesg.log
```

Try analyzing the messages at `/tmp/dmesg.log` log file or come back to here to figure out the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok I just did a suspend and it automatically rebooted again. I checked the file but I don't know where to identify the problems. It's a pretty long file...

Comment: use pastebin.com and paste the content there. We dont need everything but last 50-100 lines would cover the issue I hope. Try uploading the trace logs as per your comfort.

Comment: I uploaded the file here: https://pastebin.com/4urnRxSM  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Jing, can you paste the output of `df -h` and `df -h /var` Please. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. They are here: https://pastebin.com/G8pv77Ma, https://pastebin.com/VtsysUgc. Thanks!

Comment: @Jing I am out of Ideas, lets the bounty window come, I will offer some bounty to grab attention.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate it!